# Strange screen on bootup

Tags: startup, plymouth, boot

I am having [this screen](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2a4tzbq.jpg)  to show briefly on startup every time I start Ubuntu. When Ubuntu loads I have no problems to work with it. Sometimes something similar shows on shut down but sometimes it doesn't so I couldn't take picture of it. Is this a problem? What is it?

Comment: I'd say this is normal. Depending on your distro and GPU, screens like that are normal in Ubuntu. I'd say this is not a problem. It's just a log of all the processes taking place while Ubuntu is booting up. A splashscreen only covers it and makes it less accessible, but prettier to look at.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing. But after a few seconds a splash screen does appear and I think these messages are just the process of loading the splash screen but I am not an expert so I can't be sure. Maybe it depends on how fast the PC is.

Comment: It doesn't depend on how fast the computer is, it depends on how compatible your GPU is with your desktop environment. There's not much you can do about it, but there's also no need to. You might have noticed that there really isn't anything wrong with your computer because of this :)

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong with the PC. Thanks for your answer. By the way I have installed a propriety NVidia driver. Maybe that has something to do with that loading screen, but if it is not a problem it doesn't concern me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to get similar things happens on boot up & shutdown with previous versions of Ubuntu. I ignored them and everything was fine. They changed with different upgrades of Ubuntu. Why? I don't know. Recently I had to reinstall 14.10 and I don't get those sorts of screens anymore.

I agree with Томица Кораћ, don't worry about it, you computer and installation of Ubuntu is OK.